# JavaScript Event propagation not working on Firefox on HTML Button child elements.

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button

I am trying to pass JavaScript Function on HTML Button element and its Child elements, But child element function is not trigger on the Firefox.

Its working well on the Chrome and Safari.

Test here.

HTML Block:

```
<div class="container p-5">
  <button onClick="sayButton();" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
    <span class="badge badge-light" onClick="sayDiv(event)">Hello</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function sayButton() {
 alert("button");
}

function sayDiv(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 alert("div");
}
```

**Say Div function is not working on the firefox.**

Jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jainvabhi/nmp2L7ma/3/

Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/jainvabhi/pen/VQNgZq

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Firefox will let you do this with a button element as the parent.  In my understanding, according to the [Content Model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) for the button, you should not have interactive children.  That being said, if you change the button to a div like following, it will work.

```
<div class="container p-5">
  <div onClick="sayButton();" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
    <span class="badge badge-light" onClick="sayDiv(event)">Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/9dhgte7z/)

If this is for a production application, please take into consideration potent [accessibility considerations](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/button/button.html) when using an element other than a button for this purpose.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve the same behaviour with Button tag, As button tag is supportable on Chrome and Safari.

Comment: The fiddle works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  I don't have Safari test with at the moment.  There may very well be a way to use a button, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that Using Button is working on the both Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer. 

Can you suggest any way to support <button> too instead using <div> as a parent container you suggested above on both the Firefox and Internet Explorer.